# Login does nothing in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I am working in a project now using Yii. The login action does nothing, I really confused. I don't know what to do. So here's my code. Can anyone fix it for me? Thank to you all.

1. This is the UserIdentity.php

   ```
   class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
   {
     private $_id;
     public function authenticate()
     {
      $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));

       if ($user===null) {
           $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
       }
       else if ($user->password !== md5($this->password) ) { 
                   $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
       }
       else { // Okay!
               $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;


           }
           return !$this->errorCode;
   }

    public function getId()       //  override Id
   {
         return $this->_id;
    }
        }
   ```
2. This is my actionLogin in SiteController.php

   ```
   public function actionLogin()
   {
   $model=new LoginForm;

   // if it is ajax validation request
   if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
   {
       echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
       Yii::app()->end();
   }

   // collect user input data
   if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
   {
       $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
       // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
       if($model->validate() && $model->login())
           $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
   }
   // display the login form
   $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
   }
   ```
3. At last, the authenticate function in LoginForm.php

   ```
   public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
           {
                   $identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
                   $identity->authenticate();
                   switch($identity->errorCode)
                   {
                           case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                                   Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                                   break;
                           case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                                   $this->addError('username','Username is incorrect.');
                                   break;
                           default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID
                                   $this->addError('password','Password is incorrect.');
                                   break;
                   }
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: Generally we tend to discourage "please fix it for me" posts, as it is time-consuming for readers and doesn't teach the poster much at all. Can you briefly outline for us what you've tried? When you say it does nothing, does it white-screen, throw an error, POST to the next screen without doing anything, or redirect back to home? Have you tried adding `echo` and `exit` statements in to see what _is_ actually happening? (If not, give that a go now).

Comment: Okay I'm very sorry. I have tried to log in, but yeah it redirect back to the home page without I logged in the system. I have tried many times but it always like that. Then I tried to override the $_id in useridentity.php but the result was same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this user identity class

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

private $_id;

public $role;

const ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID = 3;
const ERROR_STATUS_NOTACTIV = 4;
const ERROR_STATUS_BAN = 5;

/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
 * are both 'demo'.
 * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
 * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
public function authenticate() {
    if (strpos($this->username, "@")) {
        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $this->username));
    } else {
        $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));
    }
    if ($user === null)
        if (strpos($this->username, "@")) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if (Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->encrypting($this->password) !== $user->password)
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else if ($user->status == 0 && Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->loginNotActiv == false)
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_STATUS_NOTACTIV;
    else if ($user->status == -1)
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_STATUS_BAN;
    else {
        $this->_id = $user->id;
        $this->username = $user->username;
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

/**
 * @return integer the ID of the user record
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}

}
```

Here is login action

```
public function actionLogin() {
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $model = new UserLogin;

        // collect user input data
        if (isset($_POST['UserLogin'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['UserLogin'];
            // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
            if ($model->validate()) {
            /*=========changed HERE===============*/
            //previous code
            //$this->redirect(array("/profile"));
            $url = 'redirect where you want';
            $this->redirect(array($url));
            }
        }
        // display the login form

        $this->render('/user/login', array('model' => $model));

    } 
    else
    {  
        $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
        if($user_id != ''){
            $this->redirect(array("/profile"));
        } else
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);

    }   
}
```

And here is your model

```
class UserLogin extends CFormModel
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 * The rules state that username and password are required,
 * and password needs to be authenticated.
 */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
        // username and password are required
            array('username, password', 'required'),
        // rememberMe needs to be a boolean
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            // password needs to be authenticated
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }

/**
 * Declares attribute labels.
 */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'rememberMe'=>"Remember me next time",
            'username'=>"username or email",
            'password'=>"password",
        );
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
    public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
    {
        if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
        {
            $identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
            $identity->authenticate();
            switch($identity->errorCode)
            {
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                    $duration=$this->rememberMe ? Yii::app()->controller->module->rememberMeTime : 0;
                    Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration);
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID:
                    $this->addError("username","Email is incorrect.");
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                    $this->addError("username","Username is incorrect.");
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_NOTACTIV:
                    $this->addError("status","Your account is not activated.");
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_BAN:
                    $this->addError("status","Your account is blocked.");
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
                    $this->addError("password","Password is incorrect.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using all the above action model and user identity you can make login in yii easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neeraj Kumar, but it redirect to Homepage without I logged in. I have tried to change the codes a bit, but still the same.
Do you have another way?
My tbl_user only have username (Primary Key) and password. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have changed little bit of code in login action have a look hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks Neeraj Kumar. I have implemented it and the result is very nice